# Filter out specific page title

Tags: google-search-appliance

The GSA documentation shows how to filter out meta name-value pairs but doesn't mention how to filter out specific page titles. The nearest I could find was intitle which looks for matches on the page title. I'm trying to filter out my error page which has "Error Page" as its title from the search results. Does anyone know if this is possible?

As an aside, the reason it's coming back in the results is from 404 errors which redirect to the error page.

Answer (score 0):

Are your errors redirecting as 302 to your 404 page? In that case, the GSA will keep the links and use back-off and retry to find the page on recrawl. You can change settings to meet your requirements. [Here is the documentation on this for software v 7.4](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/74/gsa_doc_set/admin_crawl/troubleshooting.html#1076244)

Comment: If I was exclude the folder containing the error page in the robots.txt would that stop it appearing in search results? I would rather change settings in the website rather than in GSA if it could be helped, thanks

Comment: Yes, the GSA will always obey the robots.txt. [Here is a link](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/74/gsa_doc_set/admin_crawl/preparing.html#1076139) to the 7.4 documentation about controlling what content is crawled with the GSA via robots.txt

Answer (score 0):

Got a workaround going...rather than exclude on the title I added a new meta tag to my error pages meta name="pagetype" content="error"   and then added a filter for this on my search query url params ".-pagetype:error"